# Is there a simple way to get only the Browser and the OS?

Tags: php

I need to detect the browser and the OS in a way like this:

```
Browser: Chrome 8
OS:      Ubuntu 10.04
```

I have tryed this but doesn't work:

```
<?php

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
echo "Browser: ".$browser['parent']
echo "OS: ".$browser['platform']

?>
```

I get this error:

> Warning: get_browser() [function.get-browser]: browscap ini directive not set in /opt/lampp/htdocs/info.php on line 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error and [the documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) are there to be read, not ignored. Install a browscap.ini, configure its location, and try again.

Answer (score 1):

The error message shows that you have not configured settings for `get_browser` to work.

Quoting:

> In order for this to work, your
>   browscap configuration setting in
>   php.ini must point to the correct
>   location of the browscap.ini file on
>   your system.
>
> browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP,
>   but you may find an up-to-date »
>   php_browscap.ini file here.
>
> While browscap.ini contains
>   information on many browsers, it
>   relies on user updates to keep the
>   database current. The format of the
>   file is fairly self-explanatory.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp) you will find the required `php_browscap.ini` file (and you will also need to point the [`browscap`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap) setting in `php.ini` to the downloaded file).